# Import XML into SQL and combine multiple nodes into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm having the following XML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AX_PDM_DATA>
<FilePath>\\N...</FilePath>
<ArticleCategory>

<CategoryName>test</CategoryName>
<Article>
<ItemId>123</ItemId>
<StoppedList>
<StoppedStatus>0</StoppedStatus>
<StopDescriptionItem/>
</StoppedList>
<ECOList>
<ECOStatus>0</ECOStatus>
<ECODescription/>
</ECOList>
<NCList>
<NC>1</NC>
<NCnumber>NC19012836</NCnumber>
<NCCategory>ODR</NCCategory>
<NCSubCategory>LP</NCSubCategory>
<NCDescription>test</NCDescription>
</NCList>
</Article>
<Article>
<ItemId>1234</ItemId>
<StoppedList>
<StoppedStatus>1</StoppedStatus>
<StopDescriptionItem/>
</StoppedList>
<ECOList>
<ECOStatus>0</ECOStatus>
<ECODescription/>
</ECOList>
<NCList>
<NC>0</NC>
<NCnumber/>
<NCCategory/>
<NCSubCategory/>
<NCDescription/>
</NCList>
</Article>
<Article>
<ItemId>456</ItemId>
<StoppedList>
<StoppedStatus>1</StoppedStatus>
<StopDescriptionItem/>
</StoppedList>
<ECOList>
<ECOStatus>0</ECOStatus>
<ECODescription/>
</ECOList>
<NCList>
<NC>0</NC>
<NCnumber/>
<NCCategory/>
<NCSubCategory/>
<NCDescription/>
</NCList>
</Article>
<Article>
<ItemId>74.489</ItemId>
<StoppedList>
<StoppedStatus>1</StoppedStatus>
<StopDescriptionItem/>
</StoppedList>
<ECOList>
<ECOStatus>0</ECOStatus>
<ECODescription/>
</ECOList>
<NCList>
<NC>0</NC>
<NCnumber/>
<NCCategory/>
<NCSubCategory/>
<NCDescription/>
</NCList>
</Article>
<Article>
<ItemId>AB050</ItemId>
<StoppedList>
<StoppedStatus>0</StoppedStatus>
<StopDescriptionItem />
</StoppedList>
<ECOList>
<ECOStatus>1</ECOStatus>
<ECODescription>SDsdfgadfhadfhadh arfgadfadfh</ECODescription>
</ECOList>
<NCList>
<NC>1</NC>
<NCnumber>NC18005166</NCnumber>
<NCCategory>ODR</NCCategory>
<NCSubCategory>LP</NCSubCategory>
<NCDescription>check </NCDescription>
</NCList>
<NCList>
<NC>1</NC>
<NCnumber>NC18005205</NCnumber>
<NCCategory>ODR</NCCategory>
<NCSubCategory>LP</NCSubCategory>
<NCDescription>check2</NCDescription>
</NCList>
</Article>
</ArticleCategory>
</AX_PDM_DATA>
`
```

which I want to import into a SQL database. In some circumstances under the Item node we can have multiple NClist nodes. In the NClist I have NCnumbers which I want to have into a single column.
Now I created the following SQL query:

```
`DECLARE @XmlFile XML
SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\smallfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

INSERT INTO GATEWAY_Table (ITEMID, STOPPEDSTATUS, STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM, ECOSTATUS, ECODESCRIPTION, NCNUMBER)
select
   MY_XML.Item.query('ItemId').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Item.query('StoppedList/StoppedStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Item.query('StoppedList/StopDescriptionItem').value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'),
   MY_XML.Item.query('ECOList/ECOStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Item.query('ECOList/ECODescription').value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'),
   XT2.NCLIST.query('NCList/NCnumber').value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)')
FROM 
@XMlfile.nodes('AX_PDM_DATA/ArticleCategory/Article') AS MY_XML(Item)
cross apply
 item.nodes('NCList') as XT2(NCLIST)`
```

But I'm stuck now. who can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `XT2.NCLIST` has already selected the `NCList` elements. Have you tried `XT2.NCLIST.query('NCnumber').value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)')` instead?

Comment: I tried XT2.NCLIST.query('NCnumber').value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') then I got 1 value filled .
My goal is to have the following:

123 | 0 | |0|||
...
AB050 | 0 | | 1| |sdsd| NC18000;19034;45456 etc

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

No need to use the `.query()` method, just the `.value()` method is enough.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @GATEWAY_Table TABLE (
    ITEMID VARCHAR(20), 
    STOPPEDSTATUS VARCHAR(20), 
    STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM VARCHAR(max), 
    ECOSTATUS VARCHAR(20), 
    ECODESCRIPTION VARCHAR(max), 
    NCNUMBER VARCHAR(max)
);

DECLARE @XmlFile XML;

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\temp\smallfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

INSERT INTO @GATEWAY_Table (ITEMID, STOPPEDSTATUS, STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM, ECOSTATUS, ECODESCRIPTION, NCNUMBER)
SELECT Item.value('(ItemId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(StoppedList/StoppedStatus/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(StoppedList/StopDescriptionItem/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    , Item.value('(ECOList/ECOStatus/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(ECOList/ECODescription/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    , NCLIST.value('(NCnumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @XMlfile.nodes('/AX_PDM_DATA/ArticleCategory/Article') AS t1(Item)
CROSS APPLY t1.Item.nodes('NCList') as t2(NCLIST);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @GATEWAY_Table;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------+
| ITEMID | STOPPEDSTATUS | STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM | ECOSTATUS |        ECODESCRIPTION         |  NCNUMBER  |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------+
| 123    |             0 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          | NC19012836 |
| 1234   |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          | NULL       |
| 456    |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          | NULL       |
| 74.489 |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          | NULL       |
| AB050  |             0 | NULL                |         1 | SDsdfgadfhadfhadh arfgadfadfh | NC18005166 |
| AB050  |             0 | NULL                |         1 | SDsdfgadfhadfhadh arfgadfadfh | NC18005205 |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------+
```

**SQL #2**

```
INSERT INTO @GATEWAY_Table (ITEMID, STOPPEDSTATUS, STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM, ECOSTATUS, ECODESCRIPTION, NCNUMBER)
SELECT Item.value('(ItemId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(StoppedList/StoppedStatus/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(StoppedList/StopDescriptionItem/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    , Item.value('(ECOList/ECOStatus/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , Item.value('(ECOList/ECODescription/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    , Item.query('data(NCList/NCnumber)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @XMlfile.nodes('/AX_PDM_DATA/ArticleCategory/Article') AS t1(Item);
```

**Output**

```
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| ITEMID | STOPPEDSTATUS | STOPDESCRIPTIONITEM | ECOSTATUS |        ECODESCRIPTION         |       NCNUMBER        |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 123    |             0 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          | NC19012836            |
| 1234   |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          |                       |
| 456    |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          |                       |
| 74.489 |             1 | NULL                |         0 | NULL                          |                       |
| AB050  |             0 | NULL                |         1 | SDsdfgadfhadfhadh arfgadfadfh | NC18005166 NC18005205 |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my incompetence with the output. The output you have created is almost correct. Only I need AB050 as 1 item with multiple NCnumbers instead of that every NCNumber is a new line.

Comment: @GaituutH, I updated the answer. Check it out the SQL #2.

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @GaituutH, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.